# Удаление png файлов по хешу C#

Tags: c#

Хотел написать программу которая удаляет png файлы по её хеш файлу в директории

Так я получаю список файлов в директории

```
string dirName = @"C:\путь*";
        string hash = "3f11a8fb7d11082d9e1a704639414674";

        Console.WriteLine("Список действий");
        Console.WriteLine("1 - Информация каталога\n2 - Удаление хеш файлов");
        int devs = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        if (devs == 1)
        {
            if (Directory.Exists(dirName))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Подкаталоги:");
                string[] dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(dirName);
                foreach (string s in dirs)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(s);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Файлы:");
                string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(dirName);
                foreach (string s in files)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(s);
                }
```

А так я пытался отфильтровать файлы с расширением png

```
var directory = new DirectoryInfo(dirName);
FileInfo[] files = directory.GetFiles("*.png");
```

Но предположим я сделал перебор всех файлов с таким расширением, как именно мне разом удалить эти файлы по хешу ?

```
3f11a8fb7d11082d9e1a704639414674
```

Comment: Через цикл перебирайте файлы, если хэш файла == нужный хэш, то `File.Delete(path)`

Comment: @Aarnihauta Спасибо, все получилось. Напишите в качестве ответа, я отмечу его как правильный